# Ошибка линковки "многократно определенный символ"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Программа максимально упрощена

abc.h

```
     #pragma once
     class Cabc
    {
     public:
        Cabc();
        ~Cabc();
    };
```

abc.cpp

```
#include "abc.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Cabc::Cabc()
{
    cout<<"created\n";
}
Cabc::~Cabc()
{
    cout<<"deleted\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "abc.cpp"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

[image: ошибка] "вот ошибка"
Visual studio 2010
Проблема возникает из-за наличия описания конструктора/деструктора в abc.cpp. Если их убрать -такой ошибки нет. Может быть я что-то неправильно делаю?
Из-за чего такое может происходить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашей программе две единицы компиляции: `abc.cpp` и `main.cpp`. Они компилируются раздельно.

Тем не менее единица компиляции `main.cpp` включает в себя также и исходный текст файла `abc.cpp`

```
#include "abc.cpp"
         ^^^^^^^^^       

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Поэтому конструктор и деструктор оказываются определенными в двух единицах компиляции.

Я думаю, вы имеете в виду следующее

```
#include "abc.h"
         ^^^^^^^    
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```